# Contact Form 7 not sending after Wordpress 4.9.2 update

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

All of my sites using Contact Form 7 has stopped working on submit. The response container "wpcf7-mail-sent-ng" says "An error occurred while sending the message. Please try again later."

I get the following feedback:

> into:"#wpcf7-f112-o1"message:"An error occurred while sending the message. Please try again later."status:"mail_failed"

Any ideas how to resolve this? Kind of a big deal as a lot of my customers currently use CF7 on their sites.

Thx

**EDIT**

I have the same issues, which started after the WordPress 4.9.2 automatic update. I have tested sites that are running the same release of CF7 but on another version of WordPress, and there are no issues then. Seems like a WordPress problem right?

Also, nothing in the console, and I get the same message in the feedback under the Network tab in devtools.

Comment: any console errors, errors in the debug mode?

Comment: Get this: 

{into: "#wpcf7-f112-o1", status: "mail_failed",…}
into
:
"#wpcf7-f112-o1"
message
:
"Ett fel inträffade när meddelandet skulle skickas. Var god försök senare."
status
:
"mail_failed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is now resolved!

Turns out my hosting company hade issues with php mail()

To be sure this doesnt happen in the future you can follow Priyanka Modi's advice above and use WP Mail SMTP PLugin. Yet another plugin, but it works great.

Comment: I think you should accept @Prianka's answer instead of write and accept your own answer saying that she's right.

Comment: Agree with @campsjos ... Should have really accepted the correct answer.. anyway.. life goes on

Comment: Agree with @campsjos, not particularly fair to take someone's answer as the author of the question, write your own answer based on said answer, and then mark it as accepted...

Answer (score 10):

For this issue, you can follow below steps,

**These fixes include:**

- change the wordpress contact form area from section ([your-name] <[your-email]>) to info@yourserver.com.
- add all fields inside

  **or**
- Use “WP Mail SMTP plugin”. Then you configure your mail server details.

[WordPress Mail SMTP Plugin](https://ro.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/)

Once you have sent an email
 “Thank you for your message.” Possible to refresh the automatic page.

For me personally, I tried the first two options, but it only started working and sending emails after I installed the WP Mail SMTP plugin, and configured it to use the Gmail SMTP server (which required that I created a gmail account, as you need to provide a username and password when connecting to Gmail's server).

Comment: Hey! So i have to go thru all of my clients websites and change this? 
Can you break it down and explain a bit more? 
I didnt have any ploblems untill today. And it broke just beacuse the update to Wordpress 4.9.2 ? Have other sites wich are not WP 4.9.2 and they work fine!

Comment: hi ! yes you can go thru all of your clients websites and change it.. Here, I have explained the steps in details. So, you follow this. no, here it is not issue for version of wordpress 4.9.2. So, you can try it.... you get the result !!

Comment: The two "fixes" you mentioned above didnt work, so I think this is a problem in relation to the 4.9.2 release of Wordpress